# Yii2, выборка записей с предпоследней

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить такую задачу, мне нужно выводить записи в ListView начиная с предпоследней опубликованной, последнюю запись вообще не выводить. Сейчас я вот так делаю

```
$story = Story::find()->orderBy(['publish_at' => SORT_DESC]);
```

Те. получаю все записи отсортированные по дате публикации, вместе с последней.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `unset($story[0]);`

Comment: LIMIT Вообще это вопрос возник из-за нехватки фундаментальных знаний и Yii2 тут не при чем.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$story = Story::find()->orderBy(['publish_at' => SORT_DESC])->offset(1)->all();
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, Вы мне очень помогли!